# How to solve a 405 error in a class based view

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently working on my first website. But I am experiencing this problem.
I have this class:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    def translator(self, request, phrase):
        translation = ""
        for letter in phrase:
            if letter.lower() in "a":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "U"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "u"
            elif letter.lower() in "t":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "A"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "a"
            elif letter.lower() in "c":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "G"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "g"
            elif letter.lower() in "g":
                if letter.isupper():
                    translation = translation + "C"
                else:
                    translation = translation + "c"
        return translation, render(request, 'main/translator.html')
```

And the url for this class is

```
path('translator/', TranslatorView.as_view(), name='translator'),
```

When I enter to the website, it appears a HTTP 405 error.
I think I have the problem in the class. But Idk how to solve it

Comment: A 405 means you use a method (GET/POST/...) that is not allowed. You thus need to implement a `def get`, `def post`, etc. to support the corresponding HTTP methods.

Comment: How do i do that

Answer (score 1):

A 405 means you use a method (GET/POST/...) that is not allowed. You thus need to implement a `def get`, `def post`, etc. to support the corresponding HTTP methods.

For example:

```
class TranslatorView(View):
    
    def get(self, request, phrase):
        translation = ''
        for letter in phrase:
            lletter = letter.lower()
            isup = letter.isupper()
            if lletter == 'a':
                translation += 'uU'[isup]
            elif lletter == 't':
                translation += 'aA'[isup]
            elif lletter == 'c':
                translation += 'gG'[isup]
            elif lletter == 'g':
                translation += 'cC'[isup]
        return render(request, 'main/translator.html', {'translation': translation})
```

but this will not work yet, since `phrase` is not a URL parameter. You should add this to the path:

```
path('translator/<str:phrase>/', TranslatorView.as_view(), name='translator'),
```

Comment: I added the url paramateter in path, I copied the 'translator/<str:phrase>/' into the navbar but it says that it's not a registered namespace

Comment: @MarcJuegos_Yt: you of course need to add a value for the parameter, for example `{% url 'translator' 'CAGT' %}`.

Comment: @MarcJuegos_Yt: furthermore if you did not specify an `app_name = ''` in the `urls.py`, then the url is *not* prefixed with a namespace...

Comment: I didn't specify an app name because It's the settings.py. But I'm probably wrong because I'm a begginer in coding

Comment: It appears me this error: Could not parse the remainder: ''phrase'' from ''translator''phrase''

Comment: MarcJuegos_Yt: it is `'translator' 'phrase'` or `"translator" "phrase"`. A *double* quote `"` is not the same as wo single quotes `'`.

Comment: I changed it to single quotes and it appears the same error

Comment: But now it appears me this error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @MarcJuegos_Yt: you should `return` the result of the template rendering, not `translation, render(..)`, since that is a 2-tuple, and makes no sense.